# Flink convert to parquet error

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, parquet

I am trying to use flink to write a csv file as parquet.
I am using the following the code and get the error.

```
val parquetFormat = new HadoopOutputFormat[Void, String](new AvroParquetOutputFormat, job)
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath))
```

I get the following  build error. Can someone please help?

> type mismatch;  found   : parquet.avro.AvroParquetOutputFormat 
>   required:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputFormat[Void,String] ingestion.scala /flink-scala/src/main/scala/com/sc/edl/flink    line
>   75    Scala Problem

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a `HadoopOutputFormat[Void, String]` which requires an `OutputFormat[Void, String]`.

You provide an `AvroParquetOutputFormat` which extends `ParquetOutputFormat<IndexedRecord>`. `ParquetOutputFormat` is defined as `ParquetOutputFormat<T> extends FileOutputFormat<Void, T>`.

So you provide an `OutputFormat[Void, IndexedRecord]` while `HadoopOutputFormat[Void, String]` expects an `OutputFormat[Void, String]`.

You should change `parquetFormat` to

```
val parquetFormat = new HadoopOutputFormat[Void, IndexedRecord](
  new AvroParquetOutputFormat, job)
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath))
```

If the `DataSet` that you want to write out is not of type `(Void, IndexedRecord)`, you should add a `MapFunction` that converts your data into `(Void, IndexedRecord)` pairs.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, sorry but I am new with this, can you please provide the right syntax or what is wrong

Comment: I extended my answer

Comment: Niki are you able to solve it . i am also having same issue can u please help me out.

Comment: @FabianHueske Hi Fabian, thanks for your answer. Can you please give me a hint on how to convert into (Void,IndexedRecord)?I have DataSet[MyType] and use MapFunction<<MyType,(Void,MyType)>, but I cant instantiate Void. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Still the problem stays as the Flink Tuple does not support NULL Keys as of now.
Following error will occur:
`Caused by: org.apache.flink.types.NullFieldException: Field 1 is null, but expected to hold a value.`

The better choice would be to use KiteSDK as explained in this example:
https://github.com/nezihyigitbasi/FlinkParquet
So, if you need dynamic schema then this approach won't work because you need to adhere the schema strictly. Moreover, this is better for reading not for writing.

Spark DataFrame works really well with Parquet not just in terms of API but also in terms of performance. But still if one wants to use Flink, then you need to either wait for flink community to release the api or edit the parquet-hadoop code own your own, which could be a big effort.

Only these connectors are implemented yet
https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-connectors
So, my personal suggestion would be , if you can use spark so go for it, it has more mature api considering production use cases. As you stuck with the basic need with flink, you might stuck somewhere else also.

Don't waste time to find a get around with Flink as of now, I have wasted a lot of my crucial time rather going with standard options like Hive, Spark or MR.

Answer (score 0):

Extending another answer, you can instantiate the required Void type by dropping to Java:

```
// in src/main/java/com/yourOrg/FlinkUtils.java
public class FlinkUtils {
    /* Stupid hack because we can't instantiate Void in Scala */
    public static Void getVoid() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
// src/main/scala/com/yourOrg/FlinkJob.scala

val voidKeyedDataset = ds.map((FlinkUtils.getVoid, _))
voidKeyedDataset.output(...)
```